# How to avoid short circuit evaluation in C# while doing the same functionality

Tags: c#, operators, short-circuiting

Do we have any operator in C# by which I can avoid short circuit evaluation and traverse to all the conditions.

say

```
if(txtName.Text.xyz() || txtLastName.Text.xyz())
{

}

public static bool xyz(this TextBox txt)
{
//do some work.
return false;
}
```

It should evaluate all conditions irrespective of output obtained. And after evaluating last condition continues according to result obtained. ?

Comment: Why would you want to evaluate the same condition twice?

Comment: @Adrian: Take it as a sample example. xyz function may contain any kind of defination, can be a delegate or something else.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use a single bar, this will evaluated both arguments regardless of the outcome of the first result.

```
if(txtName.Text.xyz() | txtLastName.Text.xyz()) { }
```

You can also do the same with AND, i.e. You can replace `&&` with a single ampersand to get the same affect as above:

```
if(txtName.Text.xyz() & txtLastName.Text.xyz()) { } // Both sides will be called
```

Comment: Sorry for the necropost, but this is NOT the correct way to do it. This is calling a different operation, a bitwise and/or, which does require the second function to execute to return an appropriate value. This is cause weirdness if you're returning certain numerical values.

Comment: @BennyMackney got an example?

Comment: Doing something like 

var a = funcA();
var b = funcB();
if(a || b)

will make it much clearer what you're trying to do. If you do it with the single symbol version (the bitwise and/or) you will get weirdness, particularly with and (&). For example, (4&8) == 0, which is false, whereas 4 && 8 is true.

Now C# stops this (because you're turning ints into bools without explicitly casting it) but other languages (e.g. Javascript) will operate differently. For example, in my JS console:

if(4&8){console.log('this should exec right?');}else if(4&&8){console.log("Wrong!");}
VM321:1 Wrong!

Comment: @BennyMackney this is a C# question. The OP asked how to call both methods in an if statement and this answer satisfies that. While this answer is correct, I agree that it's not best practice. Best practice would be to call both methods separately for readability and then combine their results into the if statement. Ie bool answerA = funcA(); bool answerB = funcA(). if (answerA && answerB){ // Do something }.

Comment: I know. But Javascript was also mentioned, and this is a comment and not an actual answer, so I was speaking in a broader sense.

Comment: This was just what I needed. Given that @BennyMackney didn't seem to have any rationale for disliking this approach (except in an unrelated language), I'm using it!

Answer (score 7):

Just use a single bar;

```
if(txtName.Text.xyz() | txtLName.Text.xyz())
{

}
```