# C # register with mandatory fields that should turn red if something is wrong

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a check for my register form. If a mandatory field, which one has to fill out, is not filled in correctly or not at all, the text field should be displayed in red. At the moment I just manage to turn all fields in red, when a one of the mandatory fields is wrong, but how do I get it out that only the wrong text field turns red? I know that my example is wrong and I've already tried if else, but that did not help either.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBenutzerName.Text) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPasswort.Text) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtVorname.Text) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNachname.Text)) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text)))))
        {
            txtBenutzerName.BackColor = Color.Red;
            txtPasswort.BackColor = Color.Red;
            txtVorname.BackColor = Color.Red;
            txtNachname.BackColor = Color.Red;
            txtEmail.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Comment: By writing separate if statements rather than one big if statement?

Comment: is that the only way ?

Comment: If you group all the statements together, they are all going to get executed sequentially. Your code is there to define what needs doing, not just to look pretty. Don't get me wrong, it's nice if it can look pretty too, but your code needs to define the logic, and it sounds like you want a sequence of tests for each individual field... so "what John said"

Comment: can you tell us what type of project are you working on? is it ASP .net web app or winforms, wpf or something else.

Comment: @J.Döner: Think about what your code is designed to do. "If **any** of the textboxes is empty, turn **all** the textboxes red". What you actually want is 5 separate  rules: "If textbox A is empty, turn textbox A red" (same goes for B,C,D,E).

Answer (score 2):

You could just do a separate if statement for each:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBenutzerName.Text))
{
    txtBenutzerName.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
else
{
    txtBenutzerName.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPasswort.Text))
{
    txtPasswort.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
else
{
    txtPasswort.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
}
```

Or you could do this in one line (I've split it onto two for reading convenience) using the ternary operator:

```
txtBenutzerName.BackColor = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBenutzerName.Text) 
                             ? Color.Red : SystemColors.Window;
```

Alternatively if your validation is simply to check if they are empty or not, you could make a method like this:

```
public bool ValidateField(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
    {
        textBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
ValidateField(txtBenutzerName);
ValidateField(txtPasswort);
```

And you can do something if all are valid:

```
if(ValidateField(txtBenutzerName) & ValidateField(txtPasswort))
{
    MessageBox.Show("yay");
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot, to reset the color of the textBox if content is valid. Or it will stay red forever...

Comment: @feal So did OP. I have no idea what colour OP wants to reset to so I left that up to OP to change.

Comment: okay, the method works fine, but how can i Change the Color back ? It should be shown as a normal TextBox when its valid

Comment: Use an `else` with the action you want to happen when the `if` condition is false. I've updated my answer to include resetting the colour.

Comment: There's a problem with your 'do something if all are valid' sample: chaining the checks like that with && would make it so only the first invalid text box changed colors if multiple were invalid (due to short circuiting). The result of the if test would be correct, but the UI wouldn't be.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Ah yes, right you are. I've removed it now :)

Comment: @john: If you had used `&` instead of `&&`, there would've been no short circuiting. [Link for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244358/952296)

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this

```
List<TextBox> textBoxesToValidate = new List<TextBox> { txtBenutzerName, txtPasswort, ... };

textboxesToValidate.ForEach( x=> {x.BackColor = String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text) 
                         ? Color.Red : SystemColors.Window;});
```